# uso de el bucle for en c#

Tags: c#

hola estoy aprendiendo c# (ya tengo un poco de experiencia en python)

estoy aprendiendo sobre los bucles for y la verdad no les veo mucha utilidad si ya tengo el bucle while , se que el while es indeterminado y el for es determinado 
pero el while lo puedo hacer determinado facilmente con un contador , lo cual para mi deja sin utulidad al for

alguien me puede explicar de que va este bucle ?

otra cosa en python el for  si tiene mas utilidad ya que lo puedo usar para recorrer palabras o listas letra por letra

Comment: me causa duda tu último renglón, como sabes que eso no lo puedes hacer en `C#`

Comment: buen en realidad no lo se , se puede ? , hago esta pregunta porque hasta el momento no me parece de mucha utilidad , pero se que la debe de tener y por eso quiero saber sus ventajas respecto a while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En primer lugar un bucle `for` es una herencia de C++, y funciona de la misma manera que en este lenguaje.

El uso mas común de un for es cuando quieres iterar un numero conocido de veces y a su vez tener acceso al contador, por ejemplo;

```
var numerosPares = new List<int>();

for(var c = 0; c < 10; c++)
    numerosPares.Add(c * 2);
```

Compara las dos lineas anteriores con el equivalente usando while

```
var numerosPares = new List<int>();

var c = 0;
while (c < 10)
    numerosPares.Add(c++ * 2);
```

Hasta ahora con el `for` nos ahorramos una línea, además de separar claramente la parte donde se incrementa el contador con la parte donde se calcula el valor.

Porngamos un ejemplo más complicado con un `for`/ `while` anidado

El siguiente código:

```
var coordenadas = new List<(int,int)>();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        coordenadas.Add((i,j));
```

Tendría que ser escrito de la siguiente manera usando `while`

```
var coordenadas = new List<(int, int)>();

var i = 0;
while(i < 10)
{
    var j = 0;
    while (j < 10)
    {
        coordenadas.Add((i, j++));
    }
    i++;
}
```

Como puedes ver la cantidad de líneas va en aumento. En el caso del while que pasa si te olvidas de incremetar `i` o si lo incrementas en un lugar incorrecto, o si te olvidas de inicializar `j` a 0 en cada vuelta de `i`. Además hay una asimetría: `j` se puede incrementar con el operador de incremento postfijo: `++` sin embargo `i` necesariamente se debe incrementar al final de while en una línea aparte.

Compáralo con la sintaxis de `for` que es mucho mas claro.

Answer (score 0):

Partamos de la base que siempre existe mas de una formas de hacer las cosas.

Bien entonces teniendo esto claro puedes iterar usando `for` o `while` como guste y mejor aplique en tu codigo, pero recuerda que a veces queda mas prolijo usar una determinada instruccion.

Por ejemplo cuando iteras un numero conocido de valores el for define un scope para las variales evitando que por error se modifique fuera de este

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   Console.Write(i);
}
```

en este caso la variable `i` solo sera accesible dentro del scope del `for` una vez que salga de este no sera accesible

```
int i=0;
while(i<10){
   Console.Write(i);
   i++;
}
```

es lo mismo, claro, pero cambio el scope de la variable, con lo cual esta puede ser accedida una vez que termina el `while`

Por regla cuando iteras un numero conocido de valores usas el `for` cuadno necesits definir una condicion algo mas compleja usas el `while`, por ejemplo

```
string salir = "";

do{
   //codigo
   Console.WriteLine("Desea salir? yes/no :")
   salir = Console.ReadLine();
}while(salir != "yes")
```

alli si queda claro que debes usar el `while`,ya que ante esa condicion el `for` no aplica

En c# tambien puedes iterar los items de un `string` con el `foreach`

```
string cadena = "texto de prueba";
foreach(char letra in cadena){
   //codigo
}
```

pero en realidad se usa mas con listas y colecciones

Answer (score -1):

En C# la diferencia es clara y consiste en el modo en que se procesa la condicion: FOR se ejecuta HASTA QUE la condicion sea verdad y WHILE se ejecuta MIENTRAS la condicion sea verdadera.

El punto es que los dos son bucles es decir recorren datos o lo que sea que quieras una cantidad determinada de veces y este punto en común es lo que hace que los ciclos sean en un punto de vista iguales pero con diferente sintaxis.

Te comento que con el bucle for puedes recorrer las letras de una frase solo debes hacer antes un split.